# How to access the <div> element / DOM object from the dynamics CRM form 2016

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I need to change the background colour of the CRM form notification element in the CRM dynamics 2016 for trial purposes. I know it's unsupported but this is for end user trial. the div element details are as follows-

```
<div class="Notifications Notifications-strict Notifications-strict-bottom" id="crmNotifications" style="height:; display: block;" size="3" maxheight="51">
```

I've tried using the  `window.parent.getElementById('crmNotifications').style.backgroundColor;`

but with no luck. i've also heard that DOM element is not accessible from the entity form. is there a way i can change the background color.

Comment: Which DOM you are talking about? Are you trying to change the bg color of CRM product yellow notification banner? Are you able to see that in browser dev toolbar? Try to Inspect & set color there itself..

Comment: You should post the full code, as I just checked and the anwer by @Cavan Page is working, so you have a problem with something else. Post the full code that you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("crmNotifications").style.backgroundColor = "blue"
```

Comment: sorry. DOM element is inaccessible from a crm form. hence i'm trying to figure out a way to get that achieved.

Comment: @Raghu This answer is correct, I don't understand what do you mean by DOM inaccessible from crm form. This is still a normal website, you can modify DOM however you like, although it's unsupported. I just checked and putting such code after you call Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification will successfully change the background to blue, so you are clearily making mistake somewhere else if it's not working for you

Comment: My apologies, @Pawel Gradecki, i'm using CRM 2016 (turbo forms) hence access to the DOM is not an option unless we turn off the turbo forms and set the - **use Legacy form rendering to Yes** in the system settings in Dynamics CRM. I've set the legacy form rendering to Yes and it works.

Comment: @Raghu This is also not true, you can do it even with turbo forms. I believe that your problem is that you are trying to run this from some kind of Development Tools - this will not work. But if you run it from form script, it will work correctly. I just checked this on online system, so I'm 100% sure. If it's not working for you with turbo forms then I still believe that you are doing something wrong, but you did not post the full code, so it's hard to tell what it is.

Comment: @PawelGradecki, here's the error text- _TypeError: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference at SetBackgroundColorToBlue_  & this is the function: `function SetBackgroundColorToBlue(){ var result = Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("This campaign is in Revision Mode", "Warning", "CampaignWarning"); if(result == true) document.getElementById("crmNotifications").style.background‌​Color = "red"; }`           it works as expected when the turbo form rendering is turned off and throws an error when turned on.

Comment: Why mark this as the answer, but then comment that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a HTML web resource, add it to the form and use window.parent to access the DOM.

For example:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    window.parent.document.getElementById("crmNotifications").style.backgroundColor = "blue"
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```